# Zend - check if the back button of browser was pressed

Tags: php, zend-framework, browser, zend-form, zend-studio

This is the scenario: I fill a form and I insert something in my database. After that I am redirected automatically to another form. If the user presses the back button of the browser and thus this second form isn't filled and submited, I want to delete from the database what he previously inserted.

How can i know if the user pressed the back button of the browser?

Comment: What if user close the browser ? Thus,Try to save data temp in session & than save the it in db after both the form gets filled up !

Comment: yep,sessions are the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on the idea of inserting and then deleting. I've chosen to insert the data after both forms are filled. Thank you Rikesh Shah for the idea! And thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - there is no way to do it in Zend because it's a client-side action, not a server side. You could try finding a way to utilize javascript's `window.onunload` event (which is also [implemented in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)) on the second page but that really isn't the safest option because it might not fire in some browsers or users could have their javascript turned off.

You could save the last insert id of the first form in the session and check for its existence when you load the page next time. E.g., when the user submits the first form, you say that form A has been submitted and a record has been saved with this id. Then if the user submits the next form, you clear the flag (meaning everything went as planned). However, if the user presses the back button and goes back to the previous page, you check if the flag is set. If it is, you delete the record from the table (because user pressed back without submitting the first form).

The issue with this solution is that the browser would most likely load a cached version of the page and your PHP code wouldn't even get executed. Because of that you need to check the status upon submitting the first form. However, that creates another problem - what if the user submits the first form, goes back and closes the window? It would never run the check and would never delete the row.

In my view, the most feasible option would be to prune records of the first form that are older than, say, an hour and have not been completed using a cron job.

There is no straightforward solution, so I'd say have all fields of both forms on one page. That will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly? You want to detect that in javascript or backend code (zend)?

You could add a token (unique id) to the form and make sure the page is cached for a while so when the user clicks the back button the page won't be re-fetched from the server thus generating a new token.

Edit: Multi-steps wizards can be accomplished in multiple ways either by tracking an token when you don't have authenticated users or by making checks based on your case on the submitted data whether it has been resubmitted or not.

Comment: I want to do that in Zend. I will try to insert the data only when both forms are filled. It seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you can catch this event (look with history.back() )

but i think the better way to make it is to put a state on your DB (with the userID or something like that) & make a cron when the state stay "current" delete it